# Swift "Build" not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: swift, swift3, ubuntu-16.04, perfect

I have recently installed swift by following the commands described on https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectDocs/blob/master/guide/gettingStarted.md

Installation seems to be OK.

`swift --version` is python-swiftclient 3.2.0

but when go `swift build` it says "no such command: build"

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"python-swiftclient" has nothing to do with Apple's Swift, it's a library for the OpenStack Object Storage API.

To install Apple's Swift on Ubuntu, you need to follow the instructions [detailed at swift.org](https://swift.org/download/#using-downloads) as told on the Perfect document you're referring: "After you have installed a Swift 3.0 toolchain from Swift.org..."

You will have to install dependencies with:

$ sudo apt-get install clang libicu-dev

then extract the .tar.gz file downloaded from swift.org and set the PATH to the executable - all of this is explained on the site.